# Remoção de elementos no DOM com removeChild()

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Estou iniciando com javascript, do zero, tenho este exercício onde o objetivo é adicionar e remover nomes de cidades em uma lista no html. Sei pouca coisa de DOM. A parte de inserção já funciona, mas a de remoção não está dando certo. Alguém pode me ajudar?

```
<h1>Lista de cidades visitadas.</h1>
<ul id="city"></ul>
<p>Adicionar ou remover uma cidade da lista de cidades a serem visitadas.</p>
<input type="text" name="txt-city" id="txt-city">
<button onclick="addCity()">Adicionar Cidade</button>
<button onclick="removeCity()">Remover cidade</button>
<script>
    function addCity() {
        var nameCity = document.getElementById("txt-city").value;
        var newList = document.createElement("li");
        var contentText = document.createTextNode(nameCity);
        newList.appendChild(contentText);
        document.getElementById("city").appendChild(newList);
    }

    function removeCity() {
        var list = document.getElementById("city");
        var el = list.getElementsByTagName("li");
        var txt = document.getElementById("txt-city").value;
        var content = document.createTextNode(txt);
        var x;
        for(x = 0; x < el.length; x++) {
            if(content == el[x].value) {
                list.removeChild(list.childNodes[x]);
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pegue o texto dos elementos com `innerText` e remova-os com `outerHTML` (alternativa ao `removeChild`). Sua função de remoção está errada: `el[x].value` não existe no contexto.

`var content = document.createTextNode(txt);` também não está servindo pra nada na função.

Veja como fica correto no loop e na captura do texto:

```
function removeCity() {
  var list = document.getElementById("city");
  var el = list.getElementsByTagName("li");
  var txt = document.getElementById("txt-city").value;
  for (var x = 0; x < el.length; x++) {
    if (txt == el[x].innerText) { // comparo o texto no campo com texto nas <li>
      el[x].outerHTML = ''; // removo o elemento do DOM
    }
  }
}
```

**Veja funcionando:**

```js
function addCity() {
  var nameCity = document.getElementById("txt-city").value;
  var newList = document.createElement("li");
  var contentText = document.createTextNode(nameCity);
  newList.appendChild(contentText);
  document.getElementById("city").appendChild(newList);
}

function removeCity() {
  var list = document.getElementById("city");
  var el = list.getElementsByTagName("li");
  var txt = document.getElementById("txt-city").value;
  for (var x = 0; x < el.length; x++) {
    if (txt == el[x].innerText) {
      el[x].outerHTML = '';
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<h1>Lista de cidades visitadas.</h1>
<ul id="city"></ul>
<p>Adicionar ou remover uma cidade da lista de cidades a serem visitadas.</p>
<input type="text" name="txt-city" id="txt-city">
<button onclick="addCity()">Adicionar Cidade</button>
<button onclick="removeCity()">Remover cidade</button>
```

#### Usando `querySelector`

Você também pode usar o `querySelectorAll` e `querySelector` na função de remoção:

```
function removeCity() {
  var el = document.querySelectorAll("#city li");
  var txt = document.querySelector("#txt-city").value;
  for (var x = 0; x < el.length; x++) {
    if (txt == el[x].innerText) {
      el[x].outerHTML = '';
    }
  }
}
```

`querySelectorAll` seleciona todos o elementos de uma coleção, semelhante ao `document.getElementsByTagName`.

`querySelector` seleciona um único elemento, semelhante ao `document.getElementById`.

Esses métodos possuem maior flexibilidade pois aceitam seletores CSS completos. Exemplo: `document.querySelectorAll("#city li");`

Answer (score 0):

Acontece que você está tentando acessar o atributo `value` de uma lista (`li`) e esse atributo não existe.

Ao invés de utilizar `value`, utilize `innerHTML`

```js
function addCity() {
  var nameCity = document.getElementById("txt-city").value;
  var newList = document.createElement("li");
  var contentText = document.createTextNode(nameCity);
  newList.appendChild(contentText);
  document.getElementById("city").appendChild(newList);
}

function removeCity() {
  var list = document.getElementById("city");
  var el = list.getElementsByTagName("li");
  var city = document.getElementById("txt-city").value;
  
  for (let x = 0; x < el.length; x++) {
    if (city == el[0].innerHTML) {
      list.removeChild(list.childNodes[x]);
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<h1>Lista de cidades visitadas.</h1>
<ul id="city"></ul>
<p>Adicionar ou remover uma cidade da lista de cidades a serem visitadas.</p>
<input type="text" name="txt-city" id="txt-city" value="Salvador">
<button onclick="addCity()">Adicionar Cidade</button>
<button onclick="removeCity()">Remover cidade</button>
```